# EXECUTE IMMEDIATE fail

Tags: plsql

I'm trying to use "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE", when I run the procedure I keep getting -

> `ORA-00904: "NOV": invalid identifier.`

I checked the column like 20 times, the name is right. the table has only 2 columns - acc, run1.

also, in the output I get [using the `dbms_output.put_line (v_stat)`]:

```
update LAHAD2
set run1 = 19-NOV-17
```

am I missing something?

```
create or replace procedure lahad is

v_sec_t varchar2 (100) := 'LAHAD2';
v_date date := trunc (sysdate+10); 
v_stat varchar2 (500);

begin

v_stat :=   
'update '|| v_sec_t|| '
set run1 = ' || v_date ;

dbms_output.put_line (v_stat);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_stat;        

end Lahad;
```

Comment: Oracle is saying what is this `19-NOV-17`.. How Oracle will understand this. How will you underrstand if i say `SHSHSHSH`.. What will you interprete with this statement

Answer (score 0):

You must have this:

```
update LAHAD2 set run1 = '19-NOV-17'
```

So for this above, you must have

```
v_stat := 'update '|| v_sec_t|| ' set run1 = ''' || v_date ||'''';
```

It might also be safer to have a `to_date` around this. To expect:

```
update LAHAD2 set run1 = to_date('19-NOV-17', 'DD-MON-YY')
```

You need

```
v_stat := 'update '|| v_sec_t|| ' set run1 = to_date(''' || v_date ||''') , ''DD-MON-YY'')';
```

Hope you get the thing, especially this `''` to input single `'` in the output.